# Audit Logging in Microservices

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, microservices

We are developing Micrsoservices application using `Spring` & `Hibernate`. We have implemented `hibernate-envers` for data auditing and our database is PostgreSQL. We would like to have log auditing in a separate microservice.

How to enable audit-logging in Microservices Spring App?

Comment: you mean you don't know how to call an external service?

Comment: I know how to call external service. What I am not able visualize is how to use `hibernate-envers' in microservices.

Comment: you mean `ELK`??

Comment: @emotionlessbananas Not `ELK` but `hibernate-envers`.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. Envers plugs in every transaction in order to audit the changes made to the Hibernate entities into additional database tables. It can't possibly run in an external microservice.

Comment: @JBNizet Could you please tell how to achieve auditing in microservices?

Comment: I'm planning to built an audit logs for my application. Here is what i'm thinking, Please suggest if you have any. All the microservices should log the audit in a log file, then filebeat will read and sends the log to elastic search